# Force query to return nothing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this query for filtering a sheet by multiple criteria:

```
=query(A2:H,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G "&IF(K3="where","","where A >= date '"&TEXT(K3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")&" 
"&IF(K4="","","and A <= date '"&TEXT(K4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")&" 
"&IF(K5="","","and B matches '"&UPPER(K5)&"'")&" 
"&IF(K6="","","and C matches '"&UPPER(K6)&"'")&"
",1)
```

It works fine but, when all the arguments return false, I get the whole range, presumably as the query becomes just `select A,B,C,D,E,F,G`.

Is there any way I can force it to return nothing, or an error even. I Tried just putting a random `OR C matches 'nothing'` at the end but it still returned everything.

Comment: can you provide a sample sheet for this one? or at least show what you are working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris, you could put an IF statement around the whole QUERY.  Something like:

```
=IF(AND(K3="where",K4="",K5="",K6=""),"",QUERY(....))
```

Would that work for you?